# Port numbers appearing in the URLs on my development site under Apache and Python

Tags: html, apache, url, port-number

I've built a static site. Locally, when I serve the content with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` everything behaves normally, but when I copy the HTML onto the server and browse the site at the server's URL, some links will have a port number appended to the domain. For example: `url.com:84/path` where the correct path is `url.com/path`. The port number is usually different, always between 81-85.

It is an Apache server. I'm not experienced with web server configuration, and I'm not the admin of the server. Let me know if there is more information that can help solve my problem.

```
~> cat /etc/*release*
SuSE SLES-8 (i386)
VERSION = 8.1
UnitedLinux 1.0 (i586)
VERSION = 1.0
LSB_VERSION="1.2"
DISTRIB_ID="UnitedLinux"
DISTRIB_RELEASE="1.0"
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="UnitedLinux 1.0 (i586)"
```

Comment: How have you checked that URLs become like that? Have you checked the page source?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen that is where the browser navigates to when I click on the `a` link. In the page source, the `a` has `href="/path"` as intended

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you start the server like so:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80
```

It could be that you are running this as port `80` on you local setup, but then on the Apache server it is using ports `81` to `85` because Apache is already in use.