# Configure Wordpress to listen on a port other than 80

Tags: wordpress, server, webserver, administration, port-number

Looking to set up remote `ssh` access to a Linux box running `Wordpress`.  That part should be straight forward enough -- just reserve an `IP` address for the `MAC` address to that `NIC`.

Once that's accomplished, however, how would I go about actually using `Wordpress`?  Presumably I can configure `Wordpress` to [accept connections](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/303040/63107) and serve admin pages through another port.  But how?

This would be behind `NAT` where the `ISP` blocks port 80.   (Not for production, just to play with.)

Not a problem with [directly](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/104739/34972) entering an `IP` address and port, doesn't have to be proxy server or redirect.  Or, perhaps, start `Wordpress` [bound](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/61363/34972) to a specified port?

Comment: WP is a script that runs within a web server. WP does not bind to a port, however Apache does. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html There are likely settings within WP to set. For example, within wp-config.php, set WPSITEURL and WPHOME to include whatever port you decide to use.

Comment: If you want to work around the ISP block ngrok may help